# Images in ListView xamarin (monodroid)

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
public class myAdapter : BaseAdapter<RootObject>
{
    readonly Activity context;
    List<RootObject> objects = new List<RootObject>();
    Bitmap bm;
    View view;
    ImageView iv;

    public myAdapter(Activity context, List<RootObject> objects)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public override RootObject this[int position]
    {
        get { return objects[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return objects.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        RootObject obj = objects[position];

        view = convertView;

        if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
        {
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.listItem, null);
        }

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(web_DownloadDataCompleted);
        wc.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(obj.imageUrl));

        iv = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Image);

        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvName).Text = obj.name;
        return view;
    }


    void web_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(e.Result, 0, e.Result.Length);
            runonuithread(() =>
            {
                iv.setimagebitmap(bm);
          });
        }
    }
```

`I am working on a listView in xamarin (monodroid). I have a custom adapter for my list view. Each list item  consists of an image and text view. The image comes from a url. In my download image function I am using downloadDataAsync. But before the image is downloaded, all other work gets done and the GetView method of my adapter returns the view, with no image, and only text. Is there any way to update that image resource after the view is returned. I actually want to show all the textViews first, parallel with images keep on downloading.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Naila Could you provide part of your code at least. Will be a good way for starting...

Comment: @EliasMP i have edited my question with code. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AQuery library have solved my issue. Hope it will work for someone else as well.